# Phosphate InLine not displaying on Firefox Browser

Tags: css, wordpress, drupal, fonts, mozilla

We've noticed that Phosphate Inline is not displaying properly on Firefox, when it is on other major browsers.

The font creator says that the font is supported by Firefox 3.5 browser onward.

I've attached screen grab on Firefox and another major browser.

Comment: please attach a screenshot instead of the link of your website

Comment: What's the point of reporting this to SO? You should report the issue to the creator of the font.